# How to get the actual value of a cell with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to get values from an excel sheet however there is a column filled with dates.

[Image of that column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjRrD.png)

I want to get the value exactly how it is in the cell(22-Nov-21) but instead I'm getting the value as 2021-11-22 00:00:00

Comment: Hello, please read this: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime

Comment: openpyxl gives you a datetime object, you can format however you like.

Comment: @GedasMiksenas at the moment I am using strftime.

if(key=="IMPLEMENTATION_DATE" or key=="CREATED_DATE"):
                sql+=(sh.cell(row=i,column=col).value).strftime("%d-%b-%y")

This is what I'm using at the moment. But I also do want to know how to get the exact value that is in the cell rather than trying to format everything.

Comment: @CharlieClark Is there anyway to just get the value that's in the cell without the need for formatting?

Comment: with cell.number_format you can print format used in Excel, but I don't know yet how to apply this format in python automatically. Because the number_format can vary a lot.

Comment: The value **is** a datetime and what you see is what `__repr__` returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Openpyxl doesn't evaluate the cell contents or formatting on it's own, as it doesn't actually run Excel, just accesses the file. Therefore, when you get the cell value, you are getting the datetime object it contains, not the displayed format you see when opening Excel. You could do as @Gedas suggested and get the cell format using `cell.number_format` and try and format based on that. But it's easier to just do as @Charlie recommended and format yourself ([see the documentation for datetime for more information on formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) and [format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)).

```
import openpyxl as op
import datetime as dt

wb = op.load_workbook("Date_format.xlsx")
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

your_date = ws.cell(row=1, column=1).value
your_formatted_date = your_date.strftime("%d-%b-%y")
print(your_formatted_date)

>>>
22-Nov-21
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the value for a specific cell you would use:

```
value = worksheet.cell(row, column)
```

Comment: I did try that. However I get the value as 2021-11-22 00:00:00 rather than what is printed in the cell.

Comment: It prints the list object of the cell with the name of the active worksheet, along with the last Row (E) and the last Column (817). My file had 5 columns (E) and 817 rows. For Example: in my case it was <Cell 'Nameofmyactiveworksheet'.E817>